# Server decreasing internet bandwidth

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have Ubuntu 10.04 server up and running in my home network. Recently discovered that if I connect my notebook directly to modem, I am able to get `1.0 - 1.1MByte/s` download speed. But if I connect the same notebook to server LAN port, then I get `0.8 - 0.9MByte/s` download speed. Server hardware is more than powerful (i5 CPU with 4GB RAM) and I am not running any special services on it, basically it acts only as router. I have iptables without any traffic shaping.

How can I find where the bandwidth is lost?
Let me know what additional information is required to track this issue.

Comment: The loss as I see is not very significant. It could be sporadic. Have you measured over a long time/multiple times?

Comment: Yes, number of hours, even tried to plot data. Not going above 0.9. I'm facing this issue for couple weeks, so have been monitoring it long time.

Comment: Which speed do you get when you test the speed from the server? In other words, is it the server which establishes a slower connection to the Internet or the connection from laptop to the server?

Comment: The speed I get from server is same that I get when connecting laptop to server. It's server that establishes a slower connection to Internet, not connection from laptop to server.